# How to Remove a second occurrence of a Symbols in a string using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Input:

```
ROUND((#X# + #Y#) / #Z#,2 )
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
ROUND((@X + @Y) / @Z,2 )
```

Comment: Swift? I assume you picked the wrong tag here.

Comment: What have you tried? What about your attempt are you having trouble with? Please don't mistake SO for a [free coding service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)!

Comment: Did you try splitting on `'#'`, using a string splitter that preserves order, and reassembling the string with even rows preceded by an `'@'`?

Comment: thank for replay @habo, yes i want this

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery.

We are tokenizing the input string, and adding at sign (@) symbol for a predefined sequence of characters: X, Y, and Z.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @round VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ROUND((#X# + #Y#) / #Z#,2 )'
   , @separator CHAR(1) = '#'
   , @atsign CHAR(1) = '@';

SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(@round, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('
        for $x in /root/r/text()
        return if($x=("X","Y","Z")) then concat(sql:variable("@atsign"), $x)
        else string($x)
').value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)');
```

**Output**

```
ROUND(( @X  +  @Y ) /  @Z ,2 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yitzhak, and further I will take care of right manner of putting a problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH sampleData AS
(
    SELECT myArray = 'round(#A1# + #A2#,0)+123451'
    )

,cte2 as
    (
SELECT
     [myArray] 
    ,value as val
FROM [sampleData]
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([myArray],'#'))

,cet3 as(
select case when val like '%A%' or val like '%B%' then '@'+val 
else val end as finalformula from cte2 as A),

cet4 as(select cet3.finalformula as formula from cet3)

SELECT STRING_AGG(cet4.formula,'') AS Result FROM cet4
```

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string." If you used a string splitter that returns rows in order with an item number, e.g. one of [Jeff Moden's artworks](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), you could use the even row numbers to determine where to insert the `'@'` characters.